# Example to lose fidelity during copy

Tags: mongodb

Following descriptions is from mongodb manual. Could someone share an example to prove it? Thanks.

Warning: When using `db.collection.copyTo()` (page 24) check field types to ensure that the
operation `does not remove type information` from documents during the translation from BSON to JSON.
Consider using cloneCollection() (page 95) to maintain type `fidelity`.